# Python asyncio (aiohttp, aiofiles)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I seem to be having a difficult time understanding pythons asyncio. I have not written any code, as all the examples I see are for one-off runs. Create a few coroutine's, add them to an event loop, then run the loop, they run the tasks switching between them, done. Which does not seem all that helpful for me.

I want to use asyncio to not interrupt the operation in my application (using pyqt5). I want to create some functions that when called run in the asyncio event loop, then when they are done they do a callback.

What I imagine is. Create a separate thread for asyncio, create the loop and run it forever. Create some functions `getFile(url, fp)`, `get(url)`, `readFile(file)`, etc. Then in the UI, I have a text box with a submit button, user enters url, clicks submit, it downloads the file.

But, every example I see, I cannot see how to add a coroutine to a running loop. And I do not see how I could do what I want without adding to a running loop.

```
#!/bin/python3
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import threading

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def async_in_thread(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def _get(url, callback):
    print("get: " + url)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            result = await response.text()
            callback(result)
            return

def get(url, callback):
    asyncio.ensure_future(_get(url, callback))

thread = threading.Thread(target=async_in_thread, args=(loop, ))

thread.start()

def stop():
    loop.close()

def callme(data):
    print(data)
    stop()

get("http://google.com", callme)

thread.join()
```

This is what I imagine, but it does not work.

Comment: `asyncio.ensure_future()` will do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The OP wants to add coroutines _from a different thread_, which `ensure_future` is not designed to do.

Comment: @user4815162342: fair enough. I was focusing on the 'how do I give the asyncio event loop a new task' part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a coroutine to a loop running in a different thread, use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe%60):

```
def get(url, callback):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(_get(url, callback))
```

In general, when you are interacting with the event loop from outside the thread that runs it, you must run everything through either `run_coroutine_threadsafe` (for coroutines) or [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe) (for functions). For example, to stop the loop, use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)`. Also note that `loop.close()` must not be invoked inside a loop callback, so you should place that call in `async_in_thread`, right after the call to `run_forever()`, at which point the loop has definitely stopped running.

Another thing with asyncio is that passing explicit `when_done` callbacks isn't idiomatic because asyncio exposes the concept of futures (akin to JavaScript promises), which allow attaching callbacks to a not-yet-available result. For example, one could write `_get` like this:

```
async def _get(url):
    print("get: " + url)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()
```

It doesn't need a `callback` argument because any interested party can convert it to a task using `loop.create_task` and use `add_done_callback` to be notified when the task is complete. For example:

```
def _get_with_callback(url, callback):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(_get(url))
    task.add_done_callback(lambda _fut: callback(task.result()))
```

In your case you're not dealing with the task directly because your code aims to communicate with the event loop from another thread. However, `run_coroutine_threadsafe` returns a very useful value - a full-fledged [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) which you can use to register done callbacks. Instead of accepting a `callback` argument, you can expose the future object to the caller:

```
def get(url):
    return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(_get(url), loop)
```

Now the caller can choose a callback-based approach:

```
future = get(url)
# call me when done
future.add_done_callback(some_callback)
# ... proceed with other work ...
```

or, when appropriate, they can even wait for the result:

```
# give me the response, I'll wait for it
result = get(url).result()
```

The latter is by definition blocking, but since the event loop is safely running in a different thread, it is not affected by the blocking call.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. I just have a followup, how do I properly close this now? I got rid of callbacks, I am using the `Future` object, get returns the `run_coroutine_threadsafe` now, `data = get(...)`  then I do `data.result()` (all this works perfectly). But, when I do `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.close)` just below `data.result()` I get an error "Cannot close a running event loop". I tried wrapping a `loop.stop()` coroutine like `get` above, but that did not work either.

Comment: @Drew Since `loop.stop()` is not a coroutine, you should use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)`. As for `loop.close()`, best call it from `async_in_thread`, right after the call to `loop.run_forever()`. (`run_forever()` having completed is proof that `loop.stop()` has been processed and that the loop is no longer running.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense since `run_forever()` is blocking, adding `close()` does nothing, then in my exit call before shutting down application I run `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)` then it shuts down nicely, that worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @Drew In case of a GUI program, an equally valid option is to start the event loop thread at the beginning (with `daemon` set to true), and never bothering with stop/close. Closing the event loop is important for temporary event loops created by a library (or a test runner, and so on), where it serves to release the resources held by the loop itself. In a more typical asyncio scenario, there is only one event loop and it runs for as long as the program, and whether `close()` is called when the program is exiting anyway is of little importance.

Answer (score 1):

Install [QualMash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash) to smooth integration between Qt and asyncio.

Example from the project's README gives an inspiration for how it looks like:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QProgressBar
from quamash import QEventLoop, QThreadExecutor

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
loop = QEventLoop(app)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)  # NEW must set the event loop

progress = QProgressBar()
progress.setRange(0, 99)
progress.show()

async def master():
    await first_50()
    with QThreadExecutor(1) as exec:
        await loop.run_in_executor(exec, last_50)

async def first_50():
    for i in range(50):
        progress.setValue(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)

def last_50():
    for i in range(50,100):
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(progress.setValue, i)
        time.sleep(.1)

with loop: ## context manager calls .close() when loop completes, and releases all resources
    loop.run_until_complete(master())
```